# Unable to call API's from ASP.NET MVC App?

Tags: asp.net, api, model-view-controller, error-handling

I've created a API where I want to call another API from, for testing im using Pokemon API with PostMan. However when I want to call this API im my own API application getting an error. Code executed when API is getting called:

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("RedirectApi")]
    public async Task<object> getCall()
    {
        checkAuthorisation();
        setVariables();

        if (isAuthorized == true)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto/");
            var code = response.StatusCode;
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody);
        }
        else
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("Unauthorized");
        }       
    }
```

Im calling my API with this link:

*http://localhost:54857/GetPokemon*

Whenever I execute this using Postman in debug mode it executes but fails on this code:

*HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https:/pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto/");*

It also does not give me any feedback except what Postman gives me back:

[image]

Hope someone can help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try calling the Pokemon API from Postman. If it works, make sure your code is calling it correctly (e.g., use Fiddler to compare a working Postman request with a non-working MVC request).

Comment: Postman does work, even from my virtual machine. My App just does not.

Comment: @NielsStenden Have you tried wrapping `HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto/");
` statement in a try/catch block and then debug to see what excepting is thrown?